# Cant install Mysql2 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using ruby '2.7.5' and rails '6.0.4.7' on WSL2

I'm trying to install the mysql2 gem but I keep getting the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20231208-2396-1amnwp6.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... no
-----
Cannot find library dir(s) /home/julio/.rvm/usr/lib
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-dir
        --with-openssl-dir
        --with-openssl-include
        --without-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
        --with-openssl-lib
        --without-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

already tryed installing libmysqlclient-dev, mysql-devel, and default-libmysqlclient-dev and the error persisted.

Also tryed looking the mkmf.log but couldnt get anything out of it.
Mkmf.log:

```html
have_func: checking for rb_absint_size()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_absint_size; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_absint_singlebit_p; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_gc_mark_movable; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:14:57: error: ‘rb_wait_for_single_fd’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   14 | int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return !p; }
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:14:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: extern void rb_wait_for_single_fd();
15: int t(void) { rb_wait_for_single_fd(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:16:57: error: ‘rb_enc_interned_str’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘rb_sym_interned_p’?
   16 | int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_enc_interned_str; return !p; }
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                         rb_sym_interned_p
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <ruby.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_enc_interned_str; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/x86_64-linux -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.    -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -L/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib -lruby  -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVpuOoI.o: in function `t':
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2/conftest.c:17: undefined reference to `rb_enc_interned_str'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <ruby.h>
 4: 
 5: /*top*/
 6: extern int t(void);
 7: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 8: {
 9:   if (argc > 1000000) {
10:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
11:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
12:   }
13: 
14:   return !!argv[argc];
15: }
16: extern void rb_enc_interned_str();
17: int t(void) { rb_enc_interned_str(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Can you run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` for a more detail error message so we can go from there?

Comment: It gives the exact same message.

Comment: The mkmf.log contains checks for available methods but no explicit failure. It's failing because `Cannot find library dir(s) /home/julio/.rvm/usr/lib` coming from line 59 or 107 https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/0.5.5/ext/mysql2/extconf.rb. I'd check those lib dirs and set them explicitly in the gem install (Configuration options section in the README).